# How to retrieve all commits for a file in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am able to retrieve the commits for a file using the below URL.

```
https://gitlab.aws.site.domain.com/api/v4/projects/68456/repository/commits?path=testflow/flow.java
```

But adding the optional parameter all, ends up with empty array.

```
https://gitlab.aws.site.domain.com/api/v4/projects/68456/repository/commits?path=testflow/flow.java&all=true
```

Calling with just `path` will get me latest results ? and is `all` not for all commits across branches. I thought if ref_name is not passed it takes the default. I tried the above apis with ref_name too but the same responses.

Comment: I do not see the option `all` in the docs, maybe I am looking at the wrong page?  (I thought it would be: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html )

Comment: @Luuk https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html- Its the `commits` API

Answer (score 1):

The `all` parameter is not compatible with the `path` parameter. You must use the `path` parameter without using the `all` parameter.

If there are many changes to the file, you need to [paginate over the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/#pagination) results using multiple requests. This applies to virtually all API endpoints within GitLab that will return more than 20 results.

For example, the URL `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/278964/repository/commits?path=.gitlab-ci.yml` will return the first 20 results from the API. To get the *next* 20 pages, you will add the `page` parameter with the next page number:

- `?path=.gitlab-ci.yml&page=2` for the second page
- `?path=.gitlab-ci.yml&page=3` for the third page
- and so on

You can use the response headers to know what the next page to request is.

You may also configure the `per_page` arguments, as described in the [API docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/#offset-based-pagination) e.g., `?path=.gitlab-ci.yml&page=1&per_page=100`

Comment: yeah but adding all parameter with 'path' does return some results at times, is there any documentation around this part from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html

Comment: No, I'm unsure why the behavior is inconsistent. Seems like a bug @Scorpy but I couldn't find any open issues on this.